# iOS app not prompting to open pictures on iPad Air

Tags: html, ios, xcode, ipad, cordova

I used Phonegap to create an iOS app. In the app, I want users to be able to take or select pictures and videos from the Photos app that are later submitted into a database (code for this functionality is included below).

```html
<input type="file" name="video"/><br>
<input type="file" name="image"/>
```

This functionality works when I run the app on an iPad 4 and iPad 3 (both are on iOS 8). However, when users click "Choose file" on an iPad Air try to take a new photo or video or select a current photo and video, the app crashes. The app also doesn't show up under
Settings->Privacy->Photos as one of the apps that requested access to photos. Any guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated.